# Adding new column based on combined criteria in Pandas Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

Following on from my previous question (thanks to those responding) I'm stuck again in achieving what I suspect is possible using a `groupby` in Pandas. Here's what I'm trying to achieve. With the following example dataframe:

```
data_initial = {
"account_id": ['1001', '1001', '1001', '1002', '1002', '1002', '1002', '1002', '1002', '1002', '1002', '1002', '1002', '1003', '1003', '1003', '1003', '1003', '1003',],
"data_type": ['payment', 'payment', 'payment', 'payment', 'payment', 'plan', 'payment', 'plan', 'plan', 'payment', 'payment', 'payment', 'payment', 'payment', 'plan', 'payment', 'payment', 'payment', 'payment',],
"transaction_date": ['2022-04-01', '2022-04-12', '2022-05-02', '2022-02-02', '2022-03-01', '2022-03-15', '2022-04-01', '2022-04-01', '2022-04-13', '2022-04-26', '2022-05-01', '2022-05-04', '2022-05-10', '2022-03-10', '2022-03-25', '2022-04-05', '2022-04-16', '2022-04-24', '2022-05-05',],
"amount": ['-50', '-40', '-60', '-30', '-25', '250', '-50', '200', '200', '-25', '-25', '-25', '-25', '-20', '100', '-25', '-25', '-25', '-25',],}
```

[image: initial dataframe]

I'm looking to, effectively, groupby the `account_id` and then apply the following logic:

- IF `data_type` is "payment" AND {`account_id` has no `data_type` = "plan" OR the `transaction_date` of the record is BEFORE any `data_type` = "plan" record} then new column `classification` = "receipt_not_plan_related"
- IF `data_type` is "payment" AND {`account_id` has a `data_type` = "plan" AND `transaction_date` is AFTER any `data_type` = "plan" record} then new column `classification` = "receipt_on_plan"
- IF `data_type` is "plan" is the only instance of "plan" then new column `classification` = "only"
- IF `data_type` is "plan" AND is the FIRST instance of "plan" then new column `classification` = "initial"
- IF `data_type` is "plan" AND is NOT the FIRST and NOT the LAST instance of "plan" then new column `classification` = "expired"
- IF `data_type` is "plan" AND is the LAST instance of "plan" then new column `classification` = "current"

The result, therefore, for the example dataframe would be as follows:

[image]

Thanks again, in advance, to anyone who can help out. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and a couple of helper columns:

```
import numpy as np

df['plans'] = df.groupby('account_id')['data_type'].transform(lambda x: x.eq('plan').cumsum())
df['n_plans'] = df.groupby('account_id')['plans'].transform('max')

is_payment = df['data_type'].eq('payment')
is_plan = df['data_type'].eq('plan')
df['classification'] = np.select([is_payment & df['plans'].eq(0),
                                  is_payment & df['plans'].gt(0),
                                  is_plan & df['n_plans'].eq(1),
                                  is_plan & df['plans'].eq(1),
                                  is_plan & df['plans'].gt(1) & df['plans'].lt(df['n_plans']),
                                  is_plan & df['plans'].eq(df['n_plans'])], 
                                ['receipt_not_plan_related',
                                 'receipt_on_plan',
                                 'only',
                                 'initial',
                                 'expired',
                                 'current'])

print(df.drop(columns=['plans', 'n_plans']))
```

```
   account_id data_type transaction_date amount            classification
0        1001   payment       2022-04-01    -50  receipt_not_plan_related
1        1001   payment       2022-04-12    -40  receipt_not_plan_related
2        1001   payment       2022-05-02    -60  receipt_not_plan_related
3        1002   payment       2022-02-02    -30  receipt_not_plan_related
4        1002   payment       2022-03-01    -25  receipt_not_plan_related
5        1002      plan       2022-03-15    250                   initial
6        1002   payment       2022-04-01    -50           receipt_on_plan
7        1002      plan       2022-04-01    200                   expired
8        1002      plan       2022-04-13    200                   current
9        1002   payment       2022-04-26    -25           receipt_on_plan
10       1002   payment       2022-05-01    -25           receipt_on_plan
11       1002   payment       2022-05-04    -25           receipt_on_plan
12       1002   payment       2022-05-10    -25           receipt_on_plan
13       1003   payment       2022-03-10    -20  receipt_not_plan_related
14       1003      plan       2022-03-25    100                      only
15       1003   payment       2022-04-05    -25           receipt_on_plan
16       1003   payment       2022-04-16    -25           receipt_on_plan
17       1003   payment       2022-04-24    -25           receipt_on_plan
18       1003   payment       2022-05-05    -25           receipt_on_plan
```

Note that the records need to be sorted by `'transaction_date'` in ascending order within each `'account_id'` for this to work, since the "before", "first" and "last" conditions are checked using `GroupBy.transform()` that calculates a cumulative sum.

Comment: That's great. Thanks so much @user2246849 Much appreciated. I like the `groupby` and then `transform` approach, followed by the `np.select`. I think that technique could be really helpful in the future as well. Would I be right in thinking that the "BEFORE" requirement, in terms of ordering the "plan" records is dependent on the df being sorted by `transaction_date`? Thanks again.

Comment: @the_abbot that's right, since the "before" is handled by the `GroupBy.transform()`, the rows should be in order within the same `account_id`. Thanks, I will add it to the answer.

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much. I'm showing my noob status, but I've realised I have a few places where I can use the `np.select` method instead of a bunch of nested `np.where` statements as well. Really helpful, thanks @user2246849.

Comment: @the_abbot ah yeah, this is perfectly normal. Happens to me all the time, too. It means your coding skills are improving!